# Html Form can't deliver data to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I want to insert data to database via html form. I tried everything but after clicking the submit button, I get a blank page with no error messages. But the date isn't insert to the database. Can you help me?

**register.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["page"])){

    if($_GET["page"] == "2"){

     $user = strtolower($_POST["user"]);
     $pw   = md5($_POST["pw"]);
     $pw2   = md5($_POST["pw2"]);   

    if($pw != $pw2){

        echo "Deine Passwörter stimmen nicht über ein. Bitte wiederhole deine Eingabe... <a href='register.php'>zurück</a>";

    } else {

        $verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost", "user1", "") or die ("error");

        mysql_select_db("michael29") or die ("connection not possible");

        $control = 0;
        $abfrage = "SELECT user FROM login WHERE user = '$user'";
        $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
        {

            $control++;
        }
        if($control != 0){

            echo "Username schon vergeben. Bitte verwende einen anderen Usernamen... <a href='register.php'>zurück</a>";

        }


        mysql_close($verbindung);

    }

    }

}


?>
```

Comment: What is your form? Are you using method='post' but $_GET in php? What is the name you are using on your submit button?

Comment: There is no INSERT here.

Comment: Check for errors. You say you're not getting any, which is probably because you're not checking for them in any way.

Comment: Don't use this code, it's totally unsafe. Use mysqli/pdo with a prepared statement and password_hash()/password_verify().

Comment: $_GET is just for register.php?page=2 and im using method='post' to get the data from the register form. Theres no name on the submit button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You missed the second parameter to connect to the database. This line has an error:

```
mysql_select_db("michael29") or die ("connection not possible");
```

Replace it by:

```
mysql_select_db("michael29", $verbindung) or die ("connection not possible");
```

And you have to take care with the extensions you are using to work with mysql. Those one you have on your code were deprecated on PHP 5.5.0 version and since PHP 7.0.0 version they were removed.

Comment: Much thanks. I think i have to revise the whole code. Have a great day.

Comment: no problem bro. I'm glad I did help! Have a nice day!